# How to center the image in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I center this image so that it would be centered. I was planning on putting the buttons inside the image and then position them all together in the center of the container. But the menu keeps on going with the one with the green banner if i try on fixing it. Here are my HTML and CSS codes so far:
**HTML**

```
<div id="difficultyButton" class="col-lg-12 level mt" style="display:none; text-align:center;">
    <button type="button" class="myButton  " id="btn_easy">Easy</button> 
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="myButton " id="btn_medium">Medium</button> 
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="myButton " id="btn_hard">Hard</button> 
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="myButton mt " id="btn_exitStart">Exit</button> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.level{
   height: 530px;
   width: 600px;
   -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   -webkit-align-content: center;
   background-image: url("../images/CYL/levels.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

myButton {
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #3e7327;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #3e7327;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #3e7327;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #33a6cc 50%, #0099cc 50%); 
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%,#33a6cc), color-stop(50%,#0099cc)); 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #33a6cc 50%,#0099cc 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #33a6cc 50%,#0099cc 50%); 
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #33a6cc 50%,#0099cc 50%); 
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #33a6cc 50%,#0099cc 50%); 
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#33a6cc', endColorstr='#0099cc',GradientType=0 );
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  border-radius:3px;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#ffffff;
  width: 30%;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:19px;
  padding:11px 76px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow:0px 0px 0px #5b8a3c;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

Here's how the thing currently looked:
[image: Image with green banner]

Comment: Why are you applying a 600px width to your `div#difficultyButton`? You have some layout issues. This crops the right side of your buttons, making the text inside look uncentered

Comment: Also in your css you forget the point in the class `.myButton`

Comment: I already solved my question by adding some position attributes

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your **level** class

```
 .level
 {
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

add `background-position: top center;` to the `.level` class, and i think you need move buttons little down.

Answer (score 0):

Try add class `center-block` into `#difficultyButton` container

Answer (score 0):

I just added some position attributes to .level and .myButton so that the button would be on top of the image.`position: absolute;` and `position: relative`are what I added respectively.